# Object as query string param in API on Open API Specification Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, query-string

I have an API which is accepting query param as Object. I am using this to add multiple filters to filter the result.

When I hit the request from swagger, I am getting null for my filter object in the controller.

`userFilter` is the POJO class. It is used as a `query param` and in the controller, it is coming as null.

On swagger, it is showing as below

[image: swagger screenshot]

`userFilter` object is not getting constructed and getting NullPointerException in controller class when trying to access any field from userFilter.

Comment: Please post the definition of the `userFilter` parameter from your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file, and also your controller code.

Comment: `userFilter` is the POJO class, and in the controller, it is coming as null. I have used `userFilter` as query param.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution from [swagger.io](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#schema-vs-content).

As per the explanation, `content` is used in `complex serialization scenarios` that are not covered by style and explode. For example, if we need to send a JSON string in the `query string` like so:

```
filter={"type":"t-shirt","color":"blue"}
```

In this case, we need to wrap the `parameter` schema into `content/<media-type>` as shown below.

We need to add `content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(type = "object"))}` to the `@Parameter`.

```
@Parameter(description = "Filters", required = true, content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(type = "object"))})
```

In `JSON` format it will look like below.

```
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: filter
    
    # Wrap 'schema' into 'content.<media-type>'
    content:
      application/json:  # <---- media type indicates how to serialize / deserialize the parameter content
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            type:
              type: string
            color:
              type: string
```